# SwiftUI Fetching contacts duplication

Tags: fetch, swiftui, cncontact

I have a model view that has fetching contacts function:

```
class ContactsStore: ObservableObject {

@Published var contacts = [CNContact]()

func fetch() {} ...
```

And then in my View:

```
@EnvironmentObject var store: ContactsStore

var groupedContacts: [String: [CNContact]] {
    .init (
        grouping: store.contacts,
        by: {$0.nameFirstLetter}
    )
}
     ...
       List() {
            ForEach(self.groupedContacts.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in ...
```

I've shortened my code for the convenience, will add/edit if needed. The issue I faced - every time my View is rendered the `fetch` function is called and my array of contacts is duplicated in my view. TIA for a help

UPD: Duplication happens due to method calling `fetch` in the List `.onAppear`. So I'm looking at how to call this method only once and not every time the View appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do fetch in Init() like that:

```
struct someView: View{
    var list: [Settings]
    init(){
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Settings> = Settings.fetchRequest()
        //... some order and filter if you need
        self.list = context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    }
    var body: some View{
        ...
        ForEach(list){settings in
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Didn't try it with grouping, but you asked how to fetch only once. The answer is - in init().

But you cant get the `@Environment` in `init`, so i get the `context` from `AppDelegate`. Or you can pass the `context` as `init` parameter